# Fetch a certain amount of array using Mongoose and Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have the following schema.

```
      const FeedSchema = new Schema({

          posts: [
            {
              author: {
                userType: {
                  type: String,
                  enum: ["IndustryPartner", "User", "School"]
                },
                user: {
                  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                  ref: "posts.author.userType", //<- This may cause an issue, if there are any issues with retrieving user fields, CHECK THIS
                  required: true
                },
                name: { type: String, required: true },
                avatar: { type: String, required: true }
              },
               text:""
           ]
...
```

As the system scales the amount of posts will grow, I won't want to send all 1,000 posts at once. So my question is, if I query to get the first 20 posts and then I want to get another set of 20, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Only with aggregation, but you will lose all benefits of mongoose, including references. As a side note, there is a limit of 16Mb per document. If there are a lot of long posts you may reach this limit.

Comment: @AlexBlex, thank you for your input! Do people usually handle the threshold by truncating and archiving X amount of data then?

Comment: People usually don't design documents this way

Comment: @AlexBlex, would you have made each post it's own document and have an entirely new Schema design for just posts?

Comment: Yep, that's the first thing that comes to the mind when you start thinking about pagination. Btw even in this case fetching posts 0-20 will be much faster than 5000-5020

Comment: @AlexBlex *"Only with aggregation.."* - This is not true. The [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#proj._S_slice) operator has been around for a very long time ( At least 2.2 and possibly earlier. Can't be bothered to look ) and this is essentially what the question is asking. Aggregation is really only with `$filter` or "it's" implementation of `$slice`, which are both for different purposes than what the question asks.

Comment: @NeilLunn indeed, totally forgot about it. You should put it as an answer.